# Processing result after the end of Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the Task below, and want to get the result of the  `Servico.ExportarProdutosPorArquivo(parametros)` and use it after the thread finish. Its doing this?

```
private void RealizarSolicitacao(ParametrosExportacaoProdutos parametros, FilialDaConfiguracao filial)
{                  
    ResultadoExportacaoProdutos resultado;
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => resultado = Servico.ExportarProdutosPorArquivo(parametros));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do that:

- `async`/`await` (if you use C# 5). You'll have to change your method return type to `async Task`, then use `await task1;` to wait for the results of the task. This won't block the current thread.
- `task1.Wait()` blocks until the task is finished.
- `task1.ContinueWith` schedules a continuation that will be executed once the task is completed

I would also suggest that you change your task into a `Task<ResultadoExportacaoProdutos>`, i.e. `var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Servico.ExportarProdutosPorArquivo(parametros));`. It's cleaner that way because the task doesn't write in the variable of your method scope.

The `async`/`await` version would then become

```
private async Task RealizarSolicitacao(ParametrosExportacaoProdutos parametros, FilialDaConfiguracao filial)
{                  
    var resultado = await Task.Run(() => Servico.ExportarProdutosPorArquivo(parametros));

    // do something with resultado
}
```

The blocking `Wait`/`Result` version would be:

```
private void RealizarSolicitacao(ParametrosExportacaoProdutos parametros, FilialDaConfiguracao filial)
{                  
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => Servico.ExportarProdutosPorArquivo(parametros));

    var resultado  = task1.Result;

    // do something with resultado
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
await task1;
```

Then evaluate resultado.

```
if(resultado!=null)...
```

Comment: This will not block the process?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For your example:

```
private void RealizarSolicitacao(ParametrosExportacaoProdutos parametros, FilialDaConfiguracao filial)
{                          
    Task<ResultadoExportacaoProdutos> task1 = Task<ResultadoExportacaoProdutos>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return Servico.ExportarProdutosPorArquivo(parametros);
    });

    //The Result property blocks the calling thread until the task finishes.
    ResultadoExportacaoProdutos resultado = task1.Result;
}
```